# Error running binary when exported python virtual env to linux

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have to build my own python virtual environment with required libraries for pyspark hdfs cluster.
My local machine is mac, I have created virtual env with --copies to make sure I package the binaries without softlinks.

however, when I exported this virtual env to linux machine to use the same for pyspark, I am facing an error `python3.7: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. Any suggestions how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the format of the executable files is wrong. This is a sign of copying the binary files from an `arm64` system (for example M1 Mac with virtualenv running `arm64`) and `amd64` system, as these use different binary formats.

The easiest way to move your virtualenv across operating systems is to freeze the dependencies, for example through `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and re-install them on the target machine.

After freezing the dependencies, the `requirements.txt` file will contain a list of all the python packages used, together with their versions. For example:

```
requests==1.2.3
pip-tools=3.2.1
boto3==1.3.2
```

In order to install these dependencies in the other virtualenv, use `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

This procedure saves your from a number of possible incompatibilities: **stdlib versions** and **processor architecture**. The first problem can be solved by statically compiling binaries, but this is usually available if you compile them yourself.

The second problem is more difficult, and will require either cross-compiling your binaries for `amd64` (if you compile them yourself), or just re-install the dependencies on the target machine. Indeed, if you are using an M1 mac and your virtual environment is an `arm64` one, but your hdfs cluster is `amd64`, you won't be able to run your binaries.